# Cannot find any SDK resource for embedded system

Tags: facebook-graph-api, embedded, system

We’d like to share photos to SNS, ex. FB via the camera whose OS system is ThreadX RTOS.

But we cannot find any SDK resource for ThreadX RTOS system.

Could we have any chance to share phtots to FB via ThreadX RTOS system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook's API is based on structured HTTP calls, you could write code to interact with it in any language with a networking stack; the documentation should be applicable to any language you're using, though it will probably reference Facebook's PHP or Javascript SDK in the examples.

Your biggest problem will be authentication, which requires a web browser with internet access on the device for the user to log in and grant access to your application; if you can find a way to do that, you shouldn't have other problems with the API

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly.

The problem for us is the camera cannot use Web browser due to the hardware efficiency issues. (Ex.CPU is not capable of running web browser)

So our biggest problem is indeed the authentication, we cannot find any way to pass the authentication.

If we have any chance to get contact window of FB official developer to get the solution.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Since ThreadX does support TCP/IP, can't you just send the authentication messages that a web browser would send?

Answer (score 0):

ThreadX has another package called NetX which supports TCP/IP communication.

Please see,

For NetX, 
https://rtos.com/solutions/netx/embedded-network/

NetX Duo (IP V4/v6), 
https://rtos.com/solutions/netx-duo/embedded-network-stack/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).